# What values are acceptable in ExtraScanOverlayLayoutId CardIOActivity options?

Tags: xamarin, card.io

I have a Xamarin app that needs to read a card that is not in the standard XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX format, but rather is in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Card.IO works well on normal credit cards, but on this specific type of card it is not reading the numbers, although recognizes its a card, like in this image:

https://pasteboard.co/I87FnVA.png

I've found this option CardIOActivity.ExtraScanOverlayLayoutId on CardService.StartCapture, but don't know which values are available and if I could get it to scan this type of card.

Any help?

I've followed the instructions on https://hiranpeiriscom.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/scan-credit-card-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: First of all, I would suggest you hide your CC details from the attached image secondly, have the link that you have added for the blog is the one that is not working?

Comment: No problem with the image, its a dummy card. Yes, that link is the code I've implemented. It works with regular credit card, but my intended card is a of a specific type and purpose, with numbers joined together.

Comment: I recently made a POC on card io but I faced a similar issue where the cards that have the numbers engraved in them where not detected by it, could be the same issue